# PHP/MYSQL Script - 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: php

I've PHP script that executes a big sql queires that could takes to 10 minutes.
the script works fine on localhost. also the script was working fine on server. but since yesterday it started to show this error.

```
**Service Unavailable**

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Additionally, a 503 Service Unavailable error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

and when I contacted the support team of my hosting. they came back to me that the issue is in the script. but the wired thing that the script was working just fine since 2 weeks and out of sudden since yesterday this error starts to show up.

does anyone knows to to trace the log files for such an error? because the support team they are not willing to help in this manner

Comment: I'm thinking about making indexes to speed up this big request.
But I can't be sure without knowing how many records are "scanned" by the requests, and how the database is structured can you show us more ?

Comment: Hello @r0ulito its only 25K record for now. before I ran the script and it was inserting 5 million record.

Comment: Need the error from PHP, not the one from the browser. Try to find the error in the log files, or try to log it if is not logged.

Comment: as expected the issue was related to server. I've find out that the technical support team has edited this config file /etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf  yesterday then the error starts to show up. also they reply that they increased the timeout limit of the mod_lsapi module. And as of currently, the error is no longer being generated.

Answer (score 1):

Best would be to see the server log which should tell what went wrong, but most likely it is simply the executing of a too large job that chrashed the execution. If the server is still available for other operations. The 503 means the server was doing its thing, but *opted* to abort. This could be because PHP was fine with a long execution, but MySQL timed out or refused to finish the job.

If possible, split the job up into multiple jobs and try it again in smaller chunks. If PHP can handle the time it takes, then try in a loop to make smaller request to the service (MySQL).

This kind of thing is not uncommon to occur in system that works fine sometimes, or worked for weeks, but suddenly fails.

Comment: how can I trace the server log? where its located?

Comment: Depends who gives up, but the logs are all in /var/log if server is not configured otherwise.
eg. tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log for the web site of things

But i would spend my time redesigning the job if i were you :) Sounds like the processes is simply running too long to be managed. Consider scenario where you need this to be stable and resilient. You may need to split this up in portions and design it in a way where you can pick it up from where it left off on failure?

Comment: Hello, as expected the issue was related to server. I've find out that the technical support team has edited this config file /etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf  yesterday then the error starts to show up. also they reply that they increased the timeout limit of the mod_lsapi module. And as of currently, the error is no longer being generated.